# REGEX: How do I make my regex match with all of the below mentioned strings?

Tags: regex

The following is the regex code that I've got at the moment and I have listed what currently matches and what I am unable to get it to match with as well.

```
v[\d]\.[\d]+_ABC [\w\-]+ v\d{2}\.\d - [\w\d\-, \(\)]+ \d{4}_[A-Z]{4}_20\d{2}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d\.zip
```

What matches at the moment:

```
v2.9_ABC Test v13.1 - Ga-On, 09 October 2004_ABCD_2014-07-21.zip
v2.9_ABC Test v13.1 - Jabba, 01 October 1991_ABCD_2014-07-21.zip
v2.9_ABC Test v13.1 - Wock, 23 August 2005, Temp() 2011_ABCD_2014-07-21.zip
```

What doesn't match at the moment:

```
v1.1_ABC Test v13.1 - Temp Test, 11 September 1926 _ABCD_2014-07-21.zip
v2.9_ABC Test v13.1 - Temp, 20 March 2006 (Low)_ABCD_2014-07-21.zip
v2.9_ABC Test v13.1 - Temp, 20 March 2006 (High)_ABCD_2014-07-21.zip
v2.9_ABC Test v13.1 - Temp, 02 March 1987, Alternative Attn_ABCD_2014-07-21.zip
```

Comment: der's too much of hard coding der........is it really needed?

Comment: wouldnt it be anough to search for the beginning "vn.n" and end ".zip" and allow everything in between?

Comment: Some hints `1926 _ABCD` has a space, `(Low)` does not match `\d{4}` (`(High)` and `Attn` neither).

Comment: @vks nouseforname - yes the hard coding is necessary, want to make sure user uploads the right file and not any old file.

Comment: @sp00m I've added in ( |) and that has dealt with the space. Not sure how to deal with the low or high or the Attn bit :/

Comment: Can you show some strings which shouldn't match? `.*` trivially matches any string, but probably isn't what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tweak your Regex and used following to match both specified patterns:

```
/v[\d]\.[\d]+_ABC [\w\-]+ v\d{2}\.\d - [\w\d\-, \(\)]*_[A-Z]{4}_20\d{2}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d\.zip
```

Comment: I changed your * to + and it's perfect now as I want a 1 or more as opposed to a 0 or more.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if you want the exact format match but the following matches all the input you have given.Its not totally hard coded but to some level.Precisely the start and end.

```
pattern=re.compile(r"v\d.\d_ABC \w+ v\d+.\d - .*? \S+?\d+?-\d+?-\d+?.zip")
```

The hard coding method will involve if else combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
v[\d]\.[\d]+_ABC [\w\-]+ v\d{2}\.\d - [\w\d\-, \\]+ [^\d]*?(\d{4})?_[A-Z]{4}_20\d{2}-[01]\d-[0-3]\d\.zip
```